# Using an XML catalog with Python's lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Is there a way, when I parse an XML document using lxml, to validate that document against its DTD using an external catalog file?   I need to be able to work the fixed attributes defined in a document’s DTD.

Answer (score 9):

You can add the catalog to the `XML_CATALOG_FILES` environment variable:

```
os.environ['XML_CATALOG_FILES'] = 'file:///to/my/catalog.xml'
```

See [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.lxml.devel/5907). Note that entries in `XML_CATALOG_FILES` are space-separated URLs. You can use Python's `pathname2url` and `urljoin` (with `file:`) to generate the URL from a pathname.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example? According to the [lxml validation docs](http://codespeak.net/lxml/validation.html), lxml can handle DTD validation (specified in the XML doc or externally in code) and system catalogs, which covers most cases I can think of.

```
f = StringIO("<!ELEMENT b EMPTY>")
dtd = etree.DTD(f)
dtd = etree.DTD(external_id = "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.2//EN")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lxml does not expose this libxml2 feature, grepping the source only turns up some #defines for the error handling:

```
C:\Dev>grep -ir --include=*.px[id] catalog lxml-2.1.1/src | sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/dtd.pxi: catalog.
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_FROM_CATALOG = 20 # The Catalog module
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_WAR_CATALOG_PI = 93 # 93
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_CATALOG_MISSING_ATTR = 1650
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_CATALOG_ENTRY_BROKEN = 1651 # 1651
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_CATALOG_PREFER_VALUE = 1652 # 1652
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_CATALOG_NOT_CATALOG = 1653 # 1653
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxd: XML_CATALOG_RECURSION = 1654 # 1654
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG=20
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:WAR_CATALOG_PI=93
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG_MISSING_ATTR=1650
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG_ENTRY_BROKEN=1651
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG_PREFER_VALUE=1652
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG_NOT_CATALOG=1653
lxml-2.1.1/src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi:CATALOG_RECURSION=1654
```

From the [catalog implementation in libxml2 page](http://xmlsoft.org/catalog.html) it seems possible that the 'transparent' handling through installation in /etc/xml/catalog may still work in lxml, but if you need more than that you can always abandon lxml and use the default python bindings, which do expose the catalog functions.